# DisplayIndex for DataGridViewRow?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, indexing

seems like this would be a common question, but searching yielded nothing...the `DataGridViewColumn` has a `DisplayIndex` property indicating it's index as displayed on screen (vs the `Index` property which related - I think - to the order it was added to the grid). Is there a similar concept for rows? I want to iterate through the rows as they are displayed on screen, which may change if a column is sorted.

edit: this is the WinForms `DataGridView`

Comment: WPF? WinForms? Which DataGrid are you using?

Comment: sorry, edited to include this.

Comment: We had similar requirement and we couldn't find anything as such. Hence we have come up with the solution to have the row index in the dataset bound to it.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the columns, the index for the row is the actual display position of the row.